# JQuery button fires only on second click

Tags: jquery

I find few answers on this theme, but not help for my problem.

I dynamically create table witch have button,and button are fires only on second click.

I was yesterday get help about drop-down list how do `on change` , and it is work perfect, i wrote similar code for button,and have this problem, I don't see mistake.

Code for table is:

```
$("#tblData tbody").append("<tr>" +
    "<td><input type='text' style=\"width:180px\" class=\"phone\"/></td>" +
    "<td><input type='text' style=\"width:180px\"/></td>" +
    "<td><input type='text' style=\"width:180px\"/></td>" +
    "<td style=\"overflow: hidden;\"><select style=\"width:212px\" class=\"ddl\">" + s.html() + "</ select></td>" +
    "<td style=\"overflow: hidden;\"><select style=\"width:212px\" class=\"ddl1\"></ select>  </td>" +
    "<td><input type=\"image\" id=\"btnDeleteRow\" src=\"/images/deleterow.png\" class=\"delButt\" style=\"float:right;width:16px;height:16px\" /></td>" +
"</tr>");
```

Code for dopdown change and button click are:

```
$(".partnerTable tbody").on("click", "tr", function (e) {
    $(this).on("change", ".ddl", function () {
        $(this).parent().parent().find('.ddl1').append(s1.html());
    });

    $(this).on("click", ".delButt", function () {
       var par = $(this).parent().parent();
       par.remove();
    })
 });
```

Now when i change drop down list(ddl) second list(ddl1) get values that i want, but if i whant to remove row on `delButt` i need click two times on button. Like first time getting value , and second time running.

Thanx

Comment: You add more and more `change` and `click` event handlers inside `$(".partnerTable tbody").on("click"` handler: it's very bad idea.

Comment: Probably you need something like [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/b9oku1vL/).

Comment: @Regent thanx for answers ,this code help me very much